# How to ENTIRELY remove an flvplayback from stage when going to another flvplayback on another frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

I'm trying to create an EXE projector using flash 5.5 AS3 where I have a few videos (FLVs) to show (their location is right next to the exe file in the same directory) - each load in a different frame, and all of those videos should also have a full screen option to them. Those are original videos that people WILL want to watch in full screen. It's essential for the experience...

The problem(s) I currently have (after fixing the sound that didn't stop after going to a different video) are hard to describe, but I'll try really hard.

Ok, so when I click the full screen button on a video and watch it in full screen, I will eventually want to exit the full screen, so I click on the same icon at the bottom to exit full screen (or ESC button, it's the same) and then click the navigation button to go to the SECOND FLV's frame to watch the other video. After watching the second video in full screen and then exiting full screen, flash takes me to the FIRST video's frame and that is a big problem. Also, now the button that takes me BACK to the second video's frame won't work. It's like flash is stuck.

I use the Components --> FLVPlayback 2.5 from the componant menu (I don't really know AS3 programming) and I fix its properties in the component parameters.

Also, I don't think that any of the followings are the reason for the bug, but I use these 3 scripts to stop all sound when navigating away from one frame (with an FLVplayback) to

another frame with another FLVplayback:

```
MyFLV.stop();

SoundMixer.stopAll();

MyFLV.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,xyz);
function xyz(e:Event):void{
MyFLV.stop();
}
```

I've found these online where people asked help for the sound bug I described.

The third script was suppose to remove the FLVplayback from the stage before going to another frame, but it works only when NOT GETTING INTO FULL SCREEN. I need something that will COMPLETELY remove the previous video from the stage so after exiting the SECOND viewed video, flash won't take me to a video that from some reason is still in its memory. I have something like 30 videos in my project and I need to remove each and every one of them off of the stage before navigating to the next frame to open a new FLVPlayback.

I tried to add a link to a demo I made with the problem so you can look at it, but it triggered a "oops, something went wrong" error, probably anti spam mechanism...

Comment: Why do you have few FLVPlayback components? Are they different e.g. in look? Maybe you should try to switch the source (path to FLV) only e.g. `player.source = "file.flv"`?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? e.g. what you are using for these "back" and "exit" buttons.

Comment: Remove your event listeners to enable GC or use weak references: useWeakReference:Boolean (default = false) — Determines whether the reference to the listener is strong or weak. A strong reference (the default) prevents your listener from being garbage-collected. A weak reference does not.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using only one frame and only one flvplayback instance. Otherwise you have to deal with weird bugs like the one you are getting (usually caused by misplaced or forgotten code). Of course, using only one frame requires using more code, but with the number of hard-fixes it looks like you were making for the bugs, you may end up with less code.

Don't worry, I'll walk you through everything!

Reasons to use code (as opposed to multiple frames):

1. Easier to keep track of:

   - Know where all your code is so you can easily find and fix any problems.
2. Make changes more easily

   - You want to switch an existing video?  edit a file reference and you are done.
   - Want to add a video? no more dragging a new flvplayback instance onto a new frame just add some very simple code and a button and you're done.
3. More customization

   ---

Reasons to use multiple frames (and multiple flvplayback instances):

1. easier to place visually

   - Some people find it easier when they have an actual movieclip that they can visually place on the stage
2. Less code

   ---

Here we go:

```
//import flv library
import fl.video.*;
```

This allows you to use ActionScript to manipulate the flv player

```
//video playback code-----------------------//
var myVideo:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
```

this creates an instance of FLVPlayback called myVideo (referenced from now on in the code as myVideo)

this next chunk shows many of the customizable features of the flv player.  It is not necessary to include them.

```
//places the video player on stage at x,y
myVideo.x = 115;
myVideo.y = -10;
//uses SkinOverPlayFullscreen.swf for controls
myVideo.skin = "SkinOverPlayFullscreen.swf";
//color of controls
myVideo.skinBackgroundColor = 0x333333;
//hide controls and time it takes controls to fade and reappear (milliseconds)
myVideo.skinAutoHide=true;
myVideo.skinFadeTime=300;
//add the player to the stage
addChild(myVideo);
```

And now comes the important part.  I have made buttons and added them to the stage.  I gave each of the buttons a different instance name (box1_btn, box2_btn, and box3_btn).  When someone clicks on a button, an "event" will occur.

```
//button listener code-------------------------//

//when button 1 is clicked throw button 1 event
box1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked1);
//when button 2 is clicked throw button 2 event
box2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked2);
//when button 3 is clicked throw button 3 event
box3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked3);

//play different videos for different buttons---------//

//when button 1 event is thrown
function clicked1($e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //play video 1.flv
    myVideo.source = "1.flv";

}

//when button 2 event is thrown
function clicked2($e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //play video 2.flv
    myVideo.source = "2.flv";

}

//when button 3 event is thrown
function clicked3($e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //play video 3.flv
    myVideo.source = "3.flv";

}
```

This code will not have any sounds that keep playing because two videos cannot play at the same time in one instance of the player. Nor will it have any mess-ups when you come out of fullscreen because there is only one frame for the video to go back to.

Some possible problems you may run into:

It doesn't work at all:

- Make sure you have added an instance of FLVPlayback to the library by adding an instance to the stage from the components menu (window>>components or ctrl+F7) and then deleting it from the stage (it should still appear in the library).

The playback buttons I want aren't showing up:

- There is a great explanation of how to use As3 to manipulate FLVPlayback here:

  http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3flvplayback/

  find the section about "Applying a Skin to the FLVPlayback Component" and follow it to use an adobe playback skin.  If you want to make your own unique skin I would recommend opening and editing one of the pre-made skins.  I found mine in

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS6\Common\Configuration\FLVPlayback Skins\FLA\ActionScript 3.0`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Below would be simplest way to unload the `FLVPlayback`

```
removeChild(MyFLV);
```

it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
flvPlayBack.stop();
removeChild(flvPlayBack);
```

stops the sound and removes the playback.